# Includegraphics doesn't load page of pdfs

Tags: graphics

im new to stackexchange, so this is my first question:

i want to include a page of a pdf-file.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{color} 

\begin{document}
\input{mulitpage.pdf_tex}
\includegraphics[page=2]{mulitpage.pdf}
\end{document}
```

It works fine whit the minimal example. But not in my Masters thesis...

I'm using TeXstudio on Win10 and MikTeX in the newest Version. All Packages are up-to-date, too. I even tried using TeXworks...

What can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rather use the `pdfpages` package and `\includepdf` for this. At the moment I can't remember whether `\includegraphics` has a `page` key. And you should use `graphicx` package perhaps

Comment: I found the error including a pdf_tex graphic. Inkscape uses includegraphics... I'm not willing to change every single graphic

Comment: Sigh ... `inkscape`... found that never really convincing

Comment: Please, recheck the inserted page (from `mulitpage.pdf` or `multipage.pdf`/). Keep in mind, that the opening page of a PDF document must not be the first page necessarily.

Comment: I tried two different multipage pdfs

Comment: Master's thesis: Error message? Code? MWE?

Comment: https://bwsyncandshare.kit.edu/filestable/MlNLUlM1TVBNZ3RlUUVWbURlbVNr
This is the Code and the graphic. Hope it's not to messy...

Comment: Did you rename some files? There is a mixture of `messaufbau_drauf_winkel` and `messaufbaudraufwinkel` in your file. With uniform names `messaufbau_drauf_winkel.XXX` it works fine.

Comment: off-topic, but please don't load the same package more than once.

Comment: I deactivated everythin except the packages of the miniaml example and found that it won't compile right when is use \documentclass{scrbook}
with a non scr-class everything works finee

Comment: I added a log-file to the cloud folder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as caused by outdated version, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398496/36296

Comment: sure. but i can't accept my own answer before tomorrow.

Comment: Or do you think I should delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Package `graphics` does not support key value options for `\includegraphics`. Package `graphicx` adds this support:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Also, the option for `inputenc` is wrong. The packages appends `.def` to the option and tries to load the file with that name. LaTeX does not come with `UTF8.def` but with `utf8.def`. Thus, the option name should be lowercase:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Like I wrote before, this won't do the trick...

Comment: changing to utf8, didn't change anything

Comment: @ChrisS. You had commented on *pdfpages`, but not on `graphicx`. Package `graphicx` solves the problem, that `\includegaphics` does not parse the options as key-value options. Therefore, very likely, you get a different error, if it is still not working (wrong driver, missing page, missing file, ...).

Comment: @ChrisS. Then, you have probably a case-insensitive file system. But, the document remains *wrong* and will stop working on a different system.

Comment: I changed some things. It will work now in a minimal example. But not in my big document...